# IIS folder permission issues

Tags: windows, iis

edit1:
I upgraded my windows to an enterprise version and try to remove IIS by turning of the IIS feature from this post https://superuser.com/questions/704850/how-to-restore-iis-settings-and-default-web-site, deleted the `inetpub` folder, restarted and reinstall IIS but still having same problem.

edit2:
The folder issue also happened when I tried to use Visual Studio to publish a project to folder, but later I found out it is something related to `OneDrive`, I unlink `OneDrive` from my pc and I can see and select all folders from my machine. I still having issues with Authorization but its duplicated with many other posts so please keep this one closed

I am using windows 11 home with IIS 10

Just having some problems with my IIS, when I try to create a new site, it only allow me to select or create folder under `desktop`
[image]

and if I test the settings of the default website, it has the Authorization issue like this
[image]

I tried a few solutions like adding permissions for IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, NETWORK SERVICE, DefaultAppPool,and even Everyone to allow full access to the wwwroot folder and also enable form authenctions and anonymouse authentication and tried to change the user to both IUSR or applicationpool, non of this work

Comment: Windows Home editions are not qualified for professional development environment (due to all kinds of limitations), so questions on such edition restrictions are not really useful for most developers out there. To develop and host applications on IIS, you need at least Windows 11 Pro. While alternatives like IIS Express + Jexus Manager offer you  some better user experience, they are quite different from the typical Windows Server deployment environment so not recommended.

Comment: @LexLi I upgraded to an enterprise version but still having same issue

Comment: 1) Reset IIS Manager https://serverfault.com/a/207671/8710 2) Edit `applicationHost.config` file directly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig